# Creating a db table NULL best practices

Tags: sql, database, database-design, null

Not sure on what the best practices are for dealing with `NULL` values when I have a single table where two fields are only sometimes populated creating a lot of `NULL` values in the rows.

Should the two fields be moved to a separate table creating two tables with no `NULL` values?

A join across these two tables would just return a result that equals my original table with the `NULL`'s, so what's the point in that?

Seems pointless to separate them but I have been reading a bit about avoiding null's all together in the db.

Comment: Do you run queries against those two fields?

Comment: Possible answers also here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/5227/14987

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Purely theoretically, a NULL is supposed to mean "unknown value". So - again, purely theoretically - you should design your tables when normalized so that you don't need to fill out NULL values to mean "not applicable for this row". However, this point has pretty much no relation to any practical consideration (design, performance, or query readability).
2. Practically, there are some performance considerations. You should normalize away very sparse data in the following cases:

   - There is material benefit from shortening the table (both IO wise and/or space wise). NULLs do take space, and the wider the rows the worse the performance. This is especially true when the table has a LOT of rows and there are many such sparse columns. For smaller table with only 2 such columns the benefits realized might not be worth the trouble of having an extra join.
   - Your queries have the column in question in the `WHERE` clause. IIRC, querying on a heavily NULL-ed column is rather inefficient.
   - On the other hand, at certain point, having extra joins in the query might hurt the optimizer performance (at least it does so on Sybase once your joins have 10+ tables - from taking up CPU resources when optimizer runs to actually confusing the optimizer to pick a VERY bad plan). The solution is to avoid having too-many tables due to normalization (as in, don't bother splitting your 2 columns into a separate table), or forcing the query plan. The latter is obviously Bad Juju.

Comment: `nulls` do not always take space. Using Oracle, if they are at the end of a row then they take zero bytes - and even if they are not, they take at most 1 byte.

Comment: @JackPDouglas - Didn't know that about Oracle, thanks!. That's not sadly the case in Sybase (or MS SQL server unless you use sparse column)

Answer (score 4):

Nulls cause incorrect and inconsistent results in queries and generally increase code complexity due to the special handling needed in code that has to process them. For these reasons it usually makes sense to avoid or minimise nulls in your database designs. You don't need to use nulls in queries either - although SQL unfortunately makes them very difficult to avoid. However, by not using nulls in base tables you will ensure that your data model more accurately reflects reality and you will give database users more control over how they want nulls to be used.

Comment: @dportas - could you please elaborate on "Nulls cause incorrect and inconsistent results in queries" part?

Comment: "Nulls cause incorrect and inconsistent results in queries" - only if you mix and match sentinel values and NULLs generally. I'd much prefer a clean null to an empty string or NULL. Not least with SQL Server null bitmap for example

Comment: @DVK, Null is not a value. Unlike regular values, the way SQL treats null usually doesn't make much sense in the real world. The validity of the results depend on the intended meaning of null. In practice they have many different and contradictory meanings. For example you suggested that null could be used to signify an "unknown value", however SQL does not really support that. In mathematics, reality and in common sense, x=x would evaluate to TRUE if x was unknown but it does not in SQL if x is null. Therefore SQL does not accurately treat null as meaning an "unknown value".

Comment: @gbn - I kind of sort of was making an assumption that nobody in their right mind would mix and match sentinel values and nulls.

Comment: @dportas - OK, now I see what you meant. NULLs **don't cause** incorrect and inconsistent results in queries. NULLs cause people to write bad queries whose results are VERY consistent but different from what they expect because they didn't bother to read the basic documentation.

Comment: @dportas - also, if the value is not known, then I'd intuitively expect it to never be **exactly equal** to anything. Unknown means unknown, not some special value that is identical every time. So actually SQL's support for use of NULL as "unknown" is quite perfect.

Comment: @DKV, seems like you learnt different maths and science to me! You must live in an unusualy reality if an unknown quatity is not exactly equal to itself. In any case, SQL disagrees with you because it uses nulls for things that aren't "unknown" - for example the sum of any empty set. It also evaluates nulls in expressions in ways that don't imply "unknown". Anyone who thinks nulls behave consistently in SQL certainly hasn't read the documentation well enough!

Comment: @dportas it all depends on what the `null` really represents. Eg it might mean that the colour of a product is 'unknown' (yet), or it might mean that it is not known if the product *has* a colour (what colour is gravel?)

Comment: @JackPDouglas: consider having three tables for `HAS_COLOUR`, `HAS_NO_COLOUR` and `COLOUR_UNKNOWN` then ensure each entity has one row in exactly one of the three tables. Obviously you can add a table for each meaning of "missing colour" your application requires.

Comment: @DVK: "Unknown means unknown, not some special value that is identical every time. So actually SQL's support for use of NULL as "unknown" is quite perfect" -- if that were true then `GROUP BY` on a column containing nulls would cause each null to be in its own distinct group. However, in SQL the nulls group together i.e. in this context null is indeed treated as a special value that is identical every time.

Answer (score 3):

As dportas implies in a comment, it is helpful to know what a `null` value in a particular field means - not what it means in theory, but what it means in *your data*.

I think as long as you are clear what a `null` means in your table, and if you are sure it only means *one thing*, you can make an informed pragmatic decision about whether to allow it.

Opinion: My rule of thumb is that nullable fields are fine but shouldn't multi-task

Comment: Quote from Keith Hare, who lead the SQL Standards committee: "Early on in the development of the SQL:1999 ANSI & ISO standard, there was a concept of user-defined NULL types. The idea was to allow up to 128 different types of NULLs. One then needed a mechanism for specifying which NULL type, and comparing two NULL types to see if they were the same type of NULL. The concept was very powerful from a database design standpoint, but very complex to specify in the standard. There was no indication that any of the vendors were ever likely to implement the concept, so it was eventually weeded out."

Comment: @onedaywhen hehe [beat you to it](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5222/why-shouldnt-we-allow-nulls/5223#5223)

Comment: @gbn Easy on the 'forget theory'. Theory is the backbone of RDBMS.

Answer (score 2):

Nulls are critical to have in a database. I have never yet dealt with a database that didn't allow nulls that in the end wasn't much harder to query, much harder to maintain (how do you decide what value means I don't know the answer) and usually have more bad data. Yes nulls require special handling in queries, so do things like adding a much later date (1/1/9999) as the end date to avoid having a null.

The truth is, some data is just not known at the time the record is inserted. There is no substitute for null.

Now in you case, whther you should break out to two tables depnds alot on the width of the tables and the frequency you will need to query those nullable colulmns. I would not likely move a middlename column to another table even though I had a lot of nulls becasue it is always queried with the other information in the base table. I also would be unlikely to move an end date column.  But if the columns were things that it is nice to knw byut not usually queried whenever you query the base data (such as Birthday, hair color, etc.), then a spearate table for only the records which contain the data may be fine. Remember though, when you query if you use an inner join, you eliminate all the records which don't have a value in the second table. If I would usually want all the records (like with middle name, I rarely query just to find the people with a middle name of 'Mary'), then I tend to keep them inthe same table unless the table is getting very wide and I usually don't want to query that information.

Comment: It's arguable that nulls are useful but to say that they are "critical" or that there is "no substitute" for them is going too far. Databases are just collections of facts about the world. Science, maths and logic managed to describe the world accurately for centuries before SQL and nulls came along. Even in SQL, plenty of people design databases that work perfectly well without using nulls.

Comment: Yes they do design databases without them, I have never seen one that worked well though. What do you use when you want a numeric value that will be set later and 0 has meaning for the field for instance? How does the developer know what fake value to use or what was used in the past?

Comment: @HLGEM - see my answer's point #1. What your comment referred to was the actual 100% intended use of a NULL in relational logic - "Unknown value"; and as such is definitely very difficult to dispense with - magical "invalid value" special values are Very Evil. NULL's use as "no value" that crept in over time is what is optional.