# query "not equal" doesn't work

Tags: mysql, sql

I have very simple query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `all_conversations` WHERE `deleted_1` != '1';
```

And my `deleted_1` be default is `null` or some user id, but for some reason this query always returns me 0 rows, i also tried `<>` but still no luck what could be wrong?

**EDTI** So after running more querys i find out that my problems was default value of `deleted_1` field, it was `NULL` so i modified my query and now it works fine:

```
SELECT *
FROM `all_conversations`
WHERE `deleted_1` != 'NULL'
AND `deleted_1` != 23
```

Comment: Why 1 is enclosed in quotes like a string ?

Comment: `WHERE \`deleted_1\` != 'NULL'` You shouldn´t do this. NULL is special, have a look at my answer.

Comment: @TimWolla thank you, i will do it your way.

Comment: -1 for a very unclear question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not equal <> != operator on NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658457/not-equal-operator-on-null)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM all_conversations WHERE deleted_1 <> 1 OR deleted_1 IS NULL
```

NULL values need special treatment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/working-with-null.html

I'd suggest using the diamond operator (`<>`) in favor of `!=` as the first one is valid SQL and the second one is a MySQL addition.

Comment: I'd suggest using != because more readable, and you are using mysql, not sql :).

Answer (score 12):

I recommend to use NULL-safe operator and negation

```
SELECT * FROM `all_conversations` WHERE NOT(`deleted_1` <=> '1');
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for!

Comment: This is one sexy operator.

Comment: What makes me very curious here is why this works when others fail. Simple query: SELECT * FROM AdCoupons WHERE Deleted <> '1' ORDER BY Category . . . I have never experienced this not working. Yet it fails where yours does not.

Answer (score 5):

Can you try this: `deleted_1 is not null and deleted_1 != '1'`?

```
mysql> select 0 is not null and 0 != '1', 1 is not null and 1 != '1', null is not null and null != '1';
+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------------+
| 0 is not null and 0 != '1' | 1 is not null and 1 != '1' | null is not null and null != '1' |
+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------------+
|                          1 |                          0 |                                0 |
+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------------+
```

Or this `deleted_1 is null or deleted_1 != '1'`:

```
mysql> select 0 is null or 0 != '1', 1 is null or 1 != '1', null is null or null != '1';
+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------+
| 0 is null or 0 != '1' | 1 is null or 1 != '1' | null is null or null != '1' |
+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------+
|                     1 |                     0 |                           1 |
+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------+
```

It really depends on what you wanna get back.

Answer (score 2):

Try This.. Hope It will work for you

```
SELECT *
FROM `all_conversations`
WHERE `deleted_1` IS NOT NULL
AND `deleted_1` <> 23
```

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot use arithmetic comparison operators such as =, <, or <> to test for NULL.**

To demonstrate this for yourself, try the following query:

```
mysql> SELECT 1 = NULL, 1 <> NULL, 1 < NULL, 1 > NULL;
+----------+-----------+----------+----------+
| 1 = NULL | 1 <> NULL | 1 < NULL | 1 > NULL |
+----------+-----------+----------+----------+
|     NULL |      NULL |     NULL |     NULL |
+----------+-----------+----------+----------+
```

so you have to say,

```
SELECT * FROM `all_conversations` WHERE `deleted_1` <> '1' and `deleted_1` is null;
```

**your_field IS** NULL explicitly since **NULL** cant be club with values using arithmetic operators and it has own value **BOOLEAN**

Answer (score 0):

I agree with above Answer, just add extra detail if you have multiple AND condition
like below query, you should put the column you check for not equals with or to null in first part of the Where condition, because the OR part makes your condition incorrect

```
  SELECT ts.*, ct.Name AS CategoryName
FROM MJ.Tasks  AS ts 
LEFT JOIN MJ.Lookup_Category AS ct ON ts.CategoryID = ct.ID
WHERE ts.Status!=1 OR ts.Status IS NULL AND ts.CategoryID = @CategoryID AND ts.UserID = @UserID AND  CAST(ts.EndDate AS DATE) = CAST(@EndDate AS DATE)
```

Answer (score -2):

How about removing the single quotes around the 1?

```
SELECT * FROM `all_conversations` WHERE `deleted_1` != 1;
```

Comment: This was my first thought as well, but http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/type-conversion.html seems to imply that this should happen automatically...

Comment: still nothing, at first i thought it could be problem that most of my fields are null, but even if some have a number it still doesn't select anything.

Comment: Hmm after running few more querys it finaly returned me rows where `deleted_1` is not `NULL` it's realy strange because i'm sure before it didn't return anything even if there was some numbers so i guess my problem is that field by default is `NULL` maybe i should set it to 0 then

Comment: it really depends what you want to obtain, rows that aren't `NULL` and aren't `1` or just rows that aren't `1`.