# Active record where.not returns empty array

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Following command

```
Fight.last.fight_logs.where(item_id: nil)
```

generates sql:

```
Fight Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "fights".* FROM "fights" ORDER BY "fights"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
FightLog Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "fight_logs".* FROM "fight_logs" WHERE "fight_logs"."fight_id" = $1 AND "fight_logs"."item_id" IS NULL LIMIT $2  [["fight_id", 27], ["LIMIT", 11]]
```

and returns:

```
#<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation [#<FightLog id: 30, fight_id: 27, attack: 0, block: 0, item_id: nil, user_id: 1, damage: 11.0, created_at: "2017-11-02 16:20:55", updated_at: "2017-11-02 16:20:57">, #<FightLog id: 31, fight_id: 27, attack: 0, block: 0, item_id: nil, user_id: 20, damage: 3.0, created_at: "2017-11-02 16:20:57", updated_at: "2017-11-02 16:20:57">, #<FightLog id: 33, fight_id: 27, attack: 0, block: 0, item_id: nil, user_id: 1, damage: 1.0, created_at: "2017-11-02 16:21:40", updated_at: "2017-11-02 16:21:40">, #<FightLog id: 32, fight_id: 27, attack: 0, block: 0, item_id: nil, user_id: 20, damage: 7.0, created_at: "2017-11-02 16:21:33", updated_at: "2017-11-02 16:21:40">, #<FightLog id: 34, fight_id: 27, attack: 0, block: 0, item_id: nil, user_id: 1, damage: 12.0, created_at: "2017-11-02 16:21:47", updated_at: "2017-11-02 16:21:48">, #<FightLog id: 35, fight_id: 27, attack: 0, block: 0, item_id: nil, user_id: 20, damage: 14.0, created_at: "2017-11-02 16:21:48", updated_at: "2017-11-02 16:21:48">]>
```

but

```
Fight.last.fight_logs.where.not(item_id: 1)
```

generates sql:

```
Fight Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "fights".* FROM "fights" ORDER BY "fights"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
FightLog Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "fight_logs".* FROM "fight_logs" WHERE "fight_logs"."fight_id" = $1 AND ("fight_logs"."item_id" != $2) LIMIT $3  [["fight_id", 27], ["item_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 11]]
```

and returns:

```
#<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation []>
```

How it is possible? What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should specify `NULL` value in your query since you have it in your database:

```
Fight.last.fight_logs.where('item_id != ? OR item_id IS NULL', 1)
```

This is just how SQL works:

```
select 1 != NULL;
+-----------+
| 1 != NULL |
+-----------+
|      NULL |
+-----------+
```

You can look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994408/query-not-equal-doesnt-work) to clarify the issue.
Also, I would recommend avoiding using default NULL values in your database, there is nice [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/65) about it. You can simply use `default: 0, null: false` your case.

Comment: @MrYoshiji `You have passed Hash object to #or. Pass an ActiveRecord::Relation object instead`

Comment: @MrYoshiji Using Rails 5

Comment: @Src use `.or(Flight.last.flight_logs.where(item_id: nil))` (you can store this scope in a variable)

Comment: @MrYoshiji, I prefer my current answer (IMO it is cleaner than this long scope).

Comment: I agree, but I think it is good to show the different options and then argue which one is better.