# SQL Case Statement get rid of nulls

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

I have data across two tables bound by an ID. The problem is I do not want to select the column names but the actual data inside. So I decided to use a SELECT CASE statement but it produces a table with many nulls. How would I just select the data that isn't null?

```
column value   column name
200              car
300              boat
```

SQL QUERY:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN  b.name = 'car' THEN a.value END as 'car',
CASE WHEN  b.boat= 'car' THEN a.value END as 'boat' 
WHERE a.id = b.id
```

The output is

```
CAR  BOAT
200  NULL
NULL 300
```

How would I only select none null values?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658457/not-equal-operator-in-t-sql-on-null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GROUP BY` with `MAX` for the other columns:

```
SELECT a.id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN  b.name = 'car' THEN a.value END) as 'car',
       MAX(CASE WHEN  b.boat= 'car' THEN a.value END) as 'boat' 
WHERE a.id = b.id   
GROUP BY a.id
```