# why a variable is not set in this select statement?

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have written the following stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Accounts_ValidateLogin]
   @EmailAddress varchar(255),
   @Password varchar(20)
AS
   DECLARE @UserID int

   SELECT @UserID = UserID 
   FROM Accounts_Users 
   WHERE EmailAddress = @EmailAddress and Password = @Password

   IF @UserID != NULL   
      RETURN @UserID
   ELSE
      RETURN -1
```

When this procedure is executed it shows,

```
No rows affected.
(0 row(s) returned)
@RETURN_VALUE = -1
```

But whenever I rewrite the `SELECT` statement as,

```
SELECT UserID 
FROM Accounts_Users 
WHERE EmailAddress = @EmailAddress and Password = @Password
```

The result is:

```
UserID                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
No rows affected.
(1 row(s) returned)
@RETURN_VALUE = -1
```

My question is why the variable `@UserID` is **not getting set** inside the **1st select** statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

!= NULL will not work as you expect.

Make it:

```
IF @UserID IS NOT NULL
```

The below SO question has a little information as to why, so I won't bother reposting it (it's basically because NULL is not an actual value):

[Not equal <> != operator on NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658457/not-equal-operator-in-t-sql-on-null)