# How to delete all rows that have NOT NULL in one specific column?

Tags: sql

Im trying to delete all rows that have a value in the column ' toevoeging '

I made this query:

```
DELETE FROM gebruiksoppervlakte WHERE toevoeging = NOT NULL;
```

Why is this not possible? 
So I want to keep the rows that have NULL
Thanks!

Comment: `IS NOT NULL`, rather than `= NOT NULL`.

Comment: See also [Not equal <> != operator in T-SQL on NULL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658457/not-equal-operator-in-t-sql-on-null)

Comment: `NULL` is not a value that can be directly compared similarly to other values. It has its own logic.  For example, `NULL` itself does **not**  equal `NULL`.  See http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/steve_jones/2010/10/13/common-sql-server-mistakes-_1320_-equals-null/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `IS NOT NULL` instead of `toevoeging = NOT NULL`:

```
DELETE 
FROM gebruiksoppervlakte 
WHERE toevoeging IS NOT NULL;
```

`NULL` is something that lacks a value. So using `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` means that your column is either lacking a value or not lacking a value.

Edit, this will delete everything in your table that has a value in the `toevoeging` column. If you have empty strings that you want to delete, then you will want to use:

```
DELETE 
FROM gebruiksoppervlakte 
WHERE toevoeging = '';
```

See [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6fea9/1).

If you want to delete the rows with `null` values then you will use:

```
DELETE 
FROM gebruiksoppervlakte 
WHERE toevoeging IS NULL;
```

See [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/529ef/1)

Edit #2, based on our conversation in chat you are trying to delete all rows where there is a value but that value is not an empty string.  Then the remaining rows need to be updated to `null` in the column.  As a result you need to use both a delete and an update:

```
DELETE 
FROM gebruiksoppervlakte 
WHERE toevoeging IS NOT NULL
  and toevoeging <> '';


update gebruiksoppervlakte
set toevoeging = null;
```

See [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/332f9/1)

Comment: @warnerst This will delete all rows where toevoeging is not null so if you have a value in each row, then it will delete everything. What are you trying to delete? Are the empty cells, null or empty strings?

Comment: Oh they where empty, but not ' NULL ' . So I think it should work now

Comment: @warnerst If you want to delete the rows with empty strings, see my edit.

Comment: @warnerst Are you trying to delete the `null` rows?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27186/discussion-between-bluefeet-and-warnerst)

Answer (score 0):

> When using the WHERE clause to locate rows that have a NULL value, never use the “= NULL” comparison, instead always use the IS NULL or IS NOT NULL comparison operators.

So the correct query is :

```
DELETE FROM gebruiksoppervlakte WHERE toevoeging IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because NULLs cannot be compared, the following works exactly the same as `... WHERE toevoeging IS NOT NULL` :

```
DELETE FROM gebruiksoppervlakte
WHERE toevoeging = toevoeging
   ;
```