# Issues with SQL comparison and null values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have an update query that updates a field in one table when the value does not match a field in another table.

```
UPDATE  table1
SET     a.field1 = b.field3
FROM    table1 a ,
        table2 b
WHERE   a.field2 = b.field2
        AND a.field1 <> b.field3
```

The problem I am having is that it is not picking up when a.field1 is null and b.field3 is a value OR if a.field1 is a value and b.field3 is null.

I have gotten around this by adding the following...

```
UPDATE  table1
SET     a.field1 = b.field3
FROM    table1 a ,
        table2 b
WHERE   a.field2 = b.field2
        AND ( a.field1 <> b.field3
              OR (a.field1 IS NOT NULL
              AND b.field3 IS NULL)
              OR (a.field1 IS NULL
              AND b.field3 IS NOT NULL)
            )
```

My question is more centered around why this is happening and how to best structure the query in order to prevent this?

Comment: Null equals nothing, it is an undefined value which you cannot compare to anything(even if you use `<>`). That's why null value records are omitted. Therefore you have to use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` explicitely.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Not equal <> != operator in T-SQL on NULL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658457/not-equal-operator-in-t-sql-on-null)

Comment: I ran into the "opposite" problem recently. Someone supplied a SQL statement to me involing a comparison like `WHERE val=null ...` and it  *did actually work* on our sql-server equally to `WHERE val IS NULL`! It turned out, there is a setting `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF` that was activated on our server. This (deprecated!!) setting enables null comparisons, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/en-en/library/ms188048.aspx).

Comment: Is this behavior specific to Microsoft SQL Server?

Answer (score 10):

The problem is with NULL comparison. If a.field1 or b.field3 is NULL you need to use a IS NULL or IS NOT NULL statement. You could use a default value for a.field1 and b.field3 with the ISNULL function.

```
ISNULL(a.field1,0) <> ISNULL(b.field3,0)
```

in this case there is a comparison with the value 0.

```
SELECT IIF(NULL=NULL,'true','false')  -- The result is false.  Amazing!
```

Comment: I've never used this isnull...I will try it..thank you for the new tip

Comment: @Heather: [ISNULL function is designed for presentation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/conor_cunningham_msft/archive/2010/12/18/conor-vs-more-sargable-predicates.aspx) (SELECT) and not for filtering (WHERE).

Comment: @Norberto108: Please explain. Why " ISNULL function is designed for presentation" ?

Comment: @BogdanSahlean I just wanted to understand your point of view. The link you posted has a concern on performance and execution plan to not suggest the ISNULL use in a where condition. I agree in terms, because the execution plan is a matter of further investigation like other joins, effective use of index and more. Maybe we could not simplify things with a "not for filtering" sentence. 

Best regards

Comment: @Norberto108: If "it [seems] to work" then it doesn't means is a "[good] solution". And what if `a.field1 = 0 AND b.field3 IS NULL` ?

Comment: @BogdanSahlean 0 MUST be an arbitrary and out of the scope value. The point is to keep using the <> operator. It could be -1, etc ...

Comment: @Norberto108: Don't Take It Personal. The point is to give a [good] solution, not any solution that "works".

Comment: @Norberto108: If for a row, the value of field1 is NULL and the value of field3 is 0 then the result of `ISNULL(a.field1,0) <> ISNULL(b.field3,0)` is 'false'. But the result of `a.field1 IS NULL AND b.field3 IS NOT NULL` will be 'true'.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean I didn´t take :) But i answered you on previous comment.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean I agree with Norberto here. ISNULL is just a function, you can use it anywhere you want provided you understand the risks and caveats of using functions. I often use this pattern for quick on-the-fly queries in order to avoid spaghetti-like query like the one the op came up with as solution.

Answer (score 9):

The result of comparing anything to NULL, even itself, is always NULL(not TRUE or FALSE).
Use option with EXISTS and EXCEPT operators.

```
UPDATE table1
SET a.field1 = b.field3
FROM table1 a JOIN table2 b ON a.field2 = b.field2
WHERE EXISTS (
              SELECT a.field1
              EXCEPT
              SELECT b.field3
              )
```

Comment: Far and away the best answer, as documented [here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/06/21/undocumented-query-plans-equality-comparisons.aspx). The `ISNULL()` option works great, until it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to handling the NULL logic correctly, you need to **enclose multiple conditions that are to be applied together in parentheses**.

Something like this (not sure I understood your conditions exactly).

```
UPDATE  table1
SET     a.field1 = b.field3
FROM    table1 a ,
        table2 b
WHERE   a.field2 = b.field2
        AND (
              ( a.field1 <> b.field3)
              OR (a.field1 IS NOT NULL AND b.field3 IS NULL)
              OR (a.field1 IS NULL AND b.field3 IS NOT NULL)
            )
```

Comment: Thank you...I left out the parens in the example, but they are in my code...I have edited to be more clear

Answer (score 1):

Tim Shmelter is right in his comment, `NULL` is not equal to anything- even including `NULL`. `NULL` literally means that the value is unknown.

This means, even if `a.field1` and `b.field3` both are `NULL`, the conditions `a.field1 <> b.field3` as well as `a.field1 = b.field3` both will always return false. Try it and you will see!

I think the solution here does not lie in the `IFNULL` function of SQL Server. It lies more in your joining logic. You already have your solution, i.e., the second query in your question. What I will recommend is you playing a bit more with `NULL` values so you can understand what really are they.

Comment: So from what I'm reading, ifnull almost needs to be in any comparison query?

Comment: @Rachcha - Small correction: if either (or both) a.field1 or b.field3 are NULL, the conditions a.field1 <> b.field3 and a.field1 = b.field3 will not return FALSE, but rather NULL. It will behave like FALSE in most cases (like this one) because it is not TRUE, but it's still not FALSE and i.e. can't be negated back to TRUE. If you put NOT in front (a.field1 = b.field3) it will still be NULL and behave like FALSE.

Comment: This was a very helpful comment. Looks like you have played with a lot of nulls!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `coalesce` in SQL Server to default the value of a column to a non-null value. `Coalesce` returns the first non-null value in the list.

```
UPDATE  table1
SET     a.field1 = b.field3
FROM    table1 a ,
        table2 b
WHERE   a.field2 = b.field2
        AND (
           coalesce(a.field1,-1) <> coalesce(b.field3, -1)
        )
```

I've assumed that your type is number, though you can use other data types. I've also assumed that if both values are NULL then the two rows are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

When you write in your query `a.field1 = b.field3` you actually make two assumptions: field1 in table a must contain a value and field3 in your b table must also contain a value. It is not possible to compare a 'missing information and inapplicable information' to a value. The result of this comparison is unknown. You can have a look for further information on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29#Null-specific_and_3VL-specific_comparison_predicates).

Answer (score 0):

This will check if the Column1 and Column2 is equal, Additionally used Convertion to VARBINARY to compare in case sensitive and you can remove it if not necessary.

```
--c1 = Length of Column1
--c2 = Length of Column2

ISNULL(NULLIF(CONVERT(VARBINARY(cl), LTRIM(RTRIM(Column1))), CONVERT(VARBINARY(c2),LTRIM(RTRIM(Column2)))), NULLIF(CONVERT(VARBINARY(c2),LTRIM(RTRIM(Column2))), CONVERT(VARBINARY(c1),LTRIM(RTRIM(Column1))))) IS NULL
```

You can change the end of expression to `IS NOT NULL` for checking unequal condition.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to use [CHECKSUM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189788.aspx) function

```
create table #temp
  (
    val1 varchar(255),
    val2 varchar(255)
  )

  insert into #temp values(NULL, NULL) 
  insert into #temp values(NULL, 'B') 
  insert into #temp values('A', NULL) 
  insert into #temp values('A', 'B') 
  insert into #temp values('A', 'A') 

  select *, 
  'Are Not Equal' = case 
   when val1 <> val2 or checksum(val1) <> checksum(val2) then 'true' 
   else 'false' end 
  from #temp
```