# Self Join + Left Join in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, join

I have a table that can store different messurement values with type as associated column to store measurement type.

following Is a sample table with data

[image]

I am able to self join the table to get ht and wt values based on date. My requirement is, I also need wt values of all dates even if ht for that date is not there in the table.

Sample result

[image]

EDIT: I tried below query but it is returning only first row.

```
SELECT 
  ta.uid, ta.value as 'wt', lta.value as 'ht', ta.date,ta.id as lftid, lta.id as rtid FROM 
  [test].[dbo].[tbl2] ta
     LEFT JOIN [test].[dbo].[tbl2] Lta 
        ON ta.[date] = Lta.[date]
       AND ta.[uid] = 11 WHERE 
      ta.type = 'wt'
  AND Lta.type ='ht'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With just a few changes to your query it should work:

```
SELECT 
  ta.uid, ta.value as 'wt', lta.value as 'ht', ta.date,ta.id as lftid, lta.id as rtid FROM 
  [test].[dbo].[tbl2] ta
     LEFT JOIN [test].[dbo].[tbl2] Lta 
        ON ta.[date] = Lta.[date]
       AND ta.[uid] = 11  and ta.type<>Lta.type
       WHERE 
      ta.type = 'wt'
  AND isnull(Lta.type,'ht') ='ht'
```

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you are refering to the right alias in the `where` clause effectively changes your `left join` to an `inner join`.
[Read this answer to find out why.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44696051/sql-different-between-left-join-on-and-left-join-on-where/44696191#44696191)
To avoid that, move the conditions in the `where` clause to the `on` clause:

```
SELECT ta.uid, 
       ta.value as 'wt', 
       lta.value as 'ht', 
       ta.date,
       ta.id as lftid, 
       lta.id as rtid 
FROM [test].[dbo].[tbl2] ta
LEFT JOIN [test].[dbo].[tbl2] Lta 
ON ta.[date] = Lta.[date]
AND ta.type = 'wt'
AND Lta.type ='ht'           
WHERE ta.[uid] = 11
```

Comment: It isn't giving the desired result. Instead it is creating more than expected rows with all the mvalues in wt column.