# SQL : left join with additional criteria

Tags: sql

I am doing a left outer join :

```
select * from tableA
left join tableB on tableA.tableB_id = tableB.id
```

How can I add another search criteria on tableB only for matching tableB records? (like 'and tableB.firstname like 'a_firstname%') 
If I do :

```
select * from tableA
left join tableB on tableA.tableB_id = tableB.id
where tableB.firstname like 'a_firstname%'
```

it doesn't display records where ***on tableA.tableB_id = tableB.id*** doesn't match.

Comment: Move the condition to `ON` clause. `..on tableA.tableB_id = tableB.id and tableB.firstname like 'a_firstname%'`

Comment: Also start using meaningful `Alias` names to make the query more readable

Comment: "it doesn't display records where on tableA.tableB_id = tableB.id doesn't match." Most probably you need `OR`. Show sample data and desired result please.

Comment: Please show sample data and expected resault

Comment: @Serg - Non matching records will have `NULL` values in `tableB.firstname` which will be filtered by the `tableB.firstname like 'a_firstname%'` . Implicitly it will be converted to `INNER JOIN`. So the condition should be moved to `ON` clause which tells what are the records to be joined with `tableA` instead of filtering the result

Comment: @Prdp Yes, apparently it should be moved to `ON`, but probably `OR`ed as well. or may be not, it's not clear without an example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Different between Left join on... and Left Join on..where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44696051/sql-different-between-left-join-on-and-left-join-on-where)

Comment: Moving to ON clause was the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

please check this

```
 select * from tableA
    left join tableB on tableA.tableB_id = tableB.id and tableB.firstname like 'a_firstname%'
```