# NOT Like or <> in an NVARCHAR field is also filtering out Null - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a column `StatusCode`. I want to filter out the text `Complete` without also filtering out `NULL` values.

I am using SSMS to write my query, and if I use `<>` or `NOT LIKE`, it is also filtering out the `NULL` values.

```
SELECT TOP (1) 
   dbo.WOO.WOO_StatusCode, dbo.WOO.WOO_WorkCenterID
FROM 
   dbo.WOO 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   dbo.WKE ON dbo.WOO.WOO_RecordID = dbo.WKE.WKE_WOO_RecordID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   dbo.WKO ON dbo.WOO.WOO_WorkOrderID = dbo.WKO.WKO_WorkOrderID
WHERE     
   (dbo.WKO.WKO_WorkOrderID = @WorkOrder) 
   AND (NOT (dbo.WOO.WOO_StatusCode  LIKE  N'Complete'))
ORDER BY 
   dbo.WKE.WKE_LabStopTime DESC
```

I need the NULL's to be returned, b/c the other joined tables can still return useful information related to the record.

Essentially, how do I filter on a `NVARCHAR` column without omitting `NULL` values?

Comment: I don't get the close vote here...

Comment: Thanks All. Exactly what i needed. Really appreciate the background info as well. very helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Then use `IS NULL` + `OR  <> N'Complete'`:

```
SELECT TOP (1) dbo.woo.woo_statuscode, 
               dbo.woo.woo_workcenterid 
FROM   dbo.woo 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.wke 
                    ON dbo.woo.woo_recordid = dbo.wke.wke_woo_recordid 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.wko 
                    ON dbo.woo.woo_workorderid = dbo.wko.wko_workorderid 
WHERE  ( dbo.wko.wko_workorderid = @WorkOrder ) 
AND (dbo.woo.woo_statuscode IS NULL OR dbo.woo.woo_statuscode <> N'Complete')
ORDER  BY dbo.wke.wke_labstoptime DESC
```

Why you can't select null values with `=` or `<>`:

> `<>` is Standard SQL-92; `!=` is its equivalent.  Both evaluate for
>   values, which `NULL` is not -- `NULL` is a placeholder to say there is
>   the absence of a value.
>
> Which is why you can only use `IS NULL`/`IS NOT NULL` as predicates
>   for such situations.
>
> This behavior is not specific to SQL Server. All standards-compliant
>   SQL dialects work the same way.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5658472/284240

You can change this behaviour via [`SET ANSI NULLS OFF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx).