# sqlalchemy expression not_

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following code:

```
 s = select([user.c.Title]).where(user.c.Action != 'delete')
 conn = engine.connect()
 rows = conn.execute(s).fetchall()
 print rows
 conn.close()
```

The code is supposed to fetch a list of titles where the column 'Action' is not equal to
'delete'. Everytime I run the code, I get back an empty list.
The output in the console with echo set to True is:

```
2014-08-05 16:27:31,492 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test plain returns' AS VARCHAR(60)) AS anon_1
2014-08-05 16:27:31,492 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2014-08-05 16:27:31,492 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test unicode returns' AS VARCHAR(60)) AS anon_1
2014-08-05 16:27:31,492 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2014-08-05 16:27:31,493 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT "Notes"."Title" 
FROM "Notes" 
WHERE "Notes"."Action" != ?
2014-08-05 16:27:31,493 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('delete',)
[]
```

I checked the database and there are rows which exist which do not have 'delete' in the
'Action' column.

When I use:

```
s = select([user.c.Title]).where(not_(user.c.Action != 'delete'))
```

I still get the same output.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can `"Action"` be `NULL`? is it ever? Also, to be clear, does `user` refer to the table `"Notes"`, which is a simple table (not a join or anything)?

Comment: You need to give more information about your tables, data, and class definitions to give a definite answer, but if I had to guess, your answer lies in SQL's treatment of NULL. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5658457/

Comment: **user** only refers to the table 'Notes', nothing else. The value in the Action column is usually NULL when its not 'delete'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NULL` in SQL behaves differently from `None` in Python, and SQLAlchemy in general doesn't change that. The result of the SQL expression `NULL != 'delete'` is `NULL`, not `TRUE`. In a `WHERE` clause, `NULL` is treated as false.

To turn `NULL`s in an expression into `TRUE` or `FALSE`, you can use an `IS` expression. In your example, you want to return `TRUE` if `"Action"` is different from `'delete'`, even if it's null:

```sql
("Action" != 'delete') IS NOT FALSE
```

If the expression inside the parentheses is `FALSE`, the entire expression is `FALSE`. If it is `TRUE` or `NULL`, the entire expression is `TRUE`.

To create this expression in SQLAlchemy, use [`isnot()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnElement.isnot):

```python
(user.c.Action != 'delete').isnot(False)
```

It's easier for me to understand if we rewrite this to remove a double negative:

```python
(user.c.Action == 'delete').isnot(True)
```

which should generate the SQL:

```sql
("Action" = 'delete') IS NOT TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you so much..... Your solution fixed it.. .. I tried changing the default value of the action column to 'no action'  but I still got the same problem... Im not sure if it's bug.... Anyway thanks again

Comment: Just remember that setting a default value of a column changes the value *for future inserts that do not define a value for that column*. It does not change the value of existing rows, nor does it prevent `NULL` values in that column. Those things are accomplished in different ways.