# Incorrect no. of rows fetched in SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Please consider a table named Employee with following two columns:

1. EmpId - Number(12)
2. EmpType - Varchar2(2 bytes)

EmpType has two valid values either ES or NULL.

When I fire below query I get 100 rows

```
select * from Employee;
```

Below query gives me 60 rows:

```
select * from Employee where EmpType = 'ES'
```

While `select * from Employee where EmpType <> 'ES`' gives me 0 rows.

Why so? I should get 40 rows where EmpType is not ES.

I am working on Oracle Sql DB.

Comment: try using `select * from Employee where EmpType is null` to get nulls `emptype` and `select * from Employee where EmpType is not null` to get `emptype`= `ES`

Comment: Related: [Not equal <> != operator on NULL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658457/not-equal-operator-on-null)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Null` does not equal anything, not even another null.  So to say not equal to `ES`, null is *not* not equal to `ES`.  If you get my meaning.

So to get the values you want you need `is null`.

```
select * from Employee where EmpType is null
```

Check out this article on [handling null values](http://allthingsoracle.com/checking-for-null-with-oracle-sql/)

EDIT: As noted by @Allan, in Oracle an empty string is equivalent to null.

Comment: In Oracle, an empty string is equivalent to null, so the last SQL statement will not work.

Answer (score 0):

the "<>" used with number not with nvarchar

so you should use instead :

select * from Employee where EmpType + '' like 'null'

select * from Employee where EmpType is null

Comment: "*the "<>" used with number not with nvarchar*" is plain wrong. The not equal operator `<>` can very well be used for varchar columns. The operator `+` on the other side is *only* used for numbers in SQL (to concatenate strings you have to use `||` in standard and Oracle). And the expression `EmpType + '' like 'null'` will not work at all