# unusual sql server query result

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2

Let's say I have a table called `nameAge`:

```
ID  Name  Age
1   X     12
2   Y     12
3   null  null
4   Z     12
```

and when I run a query like:

```
select * from nameAge where Age <> 12
```

it returns me an empty result set while I have row with `id 3` where `age` is different than `null`?

Using `Sql Server 2008 R2`.

Any ideas?

Edit: Possibility to be duplicate with suggested answer may be at one point but does not cover at all and it shows how to use null values when compared with null but what I wanted to ask was about the result set which includes null values

Comment: NULL is not equal to 12

Comment: @sqluser: No it isn't. It's also not equal to 12.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Not equal <> != operator on NULL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658457/not-equal-operator-on-null)

Comment: @chuex please read the edit part.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is the intended behavior. You cannot compare `NULL` values using `=` or `<>`. You have to use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`.

If you want `NULL` values only use `IS NULL`:

```
select * from nameAge where age IS NULL
```

If you want `NULL` values with `age <> 12` values, use:

```
select * from nameAge where age <> 12 OR age IS NULL
```

Comment: Note you can use `=` and `<>` when `ANSI_NULLS` is off.

Comment: **An important addendum:** The check `NULL <> 12` will not return false, but will return a boolean NULL. Which is treated like a false value, but **can not be negated** So `NOT ( NULL <> 12 )` is still boolean NULL and not true.

Comment: @Falco - You are absolutely correct, this is described in detail by the answer provided by Tim Biegeleisen and Giorgi Nakeuri

Answer (score 8):

The expression

```
WHERE NULL <> 12
```

does not return `TRUE` or `FALSE`, but actually returns `UNKNOWN`.  This means that the third record in your table will not be returned by your query.

As @ughai mentioned, you should use `IS NULL` instead to query that record:

```
SELECT * FROM nameAge WHERE age IS NULL
```

Have a look at the [Microsoft SQL Server documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa196339%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: According to the SQL Standard, the result is `UNKNOWN` rather than `NULL`. [tag:mysql] conflates `NULL` and `UNKNOWN` but most other database products (that I'm aware of) do not.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks for pointing this out, and I have updated my answer with a link to the official Microsoft documentation.

Answer (score 4):

When you are dealing with `NULLs` you should be always careful because of 3 valued logic used in `Sql Server`(when a predicate can be evaluated to `TRUE`, `FALSE` or `UNKNOWN`). Now here is a classic `select` statement where many newcomers make a mistake, suggesting that the statement would return all rows where `Age <> 12` including `NULLs`.

But if you know the easy fact that comparing `NULL` to any value, even to `NULL` itself will evaluate to `UNKNOWN` it is getting more clear what is going on. `WHERE` clause will return **ONLY** those rows where predicate is evaluated to `TRUE`. Rows where predicate evaluates to `FALSE` or `UNKNOWN` will be filtered out from resultset.

Now let's see what is going on behind the scene. You have 4 rows:

```
ID    Name    Age
1     X       12
2     Y       12
3     null    null
4     Z       12
```

and the predicate is:

```
where Age <> 12
```

When you evaluate this predicate for each row you get:

```
ID    Name    Age   Evaluation result
1     X       12    FALSE              --(because 12 <> 12 is FALSE)
2     Y       12    FALSE              --(because 12 <> 12 is FALSE)
3     null    null  UNKNOWN            --(because NULL <> 12 is UNKNOWN)
4     Z       12    FALSE              --(because 12 <> 12 is FALSE)
```

Now remember that `WHERE` clause will return only rows where predicate evaluates to `TRUE` and it is clear that you will not get any result because no row evaluates to `TRUE`.