# ADO Connection and Recordset = ""

Tags: sql, vba, connection, ado, recordset

Do CSV (comma delimited text files) have a sheet name?
Do I need to specify a range for data to copy?

My SQL skills are weak.

I am trying to get all the text from my export.csv file into a worksheet where the "Price" column is not empty and sort it by "sku".

I can open the file and build the SQL string but there must be an error?

The debugger shows the string as:

```
"SELECT * FROM [export$] WHERE price IS NOT NULL ORDER BY sku;"
```

When I try and open the Connection and Recordset the debugger shoes they both contain the value of "".

```
Set rsCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rsData = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
```

When I get to using them I go straight to my error trap.

```
rsCon.Open szConnect
rsData.Open szSQL, rsCon, 0, 1, 1
```

I am calling the subroutine with the following data:

GetData "export.csv", "export", "A:AH", "BirdFeet", "B1", "sku", True, True

Here is the complete subroutine.

```
    Public Sub GetData(SourceFile As Variant, SourceSheet As String, SourceRange As String, _
                                              TargetSheet As String, TargetRange As String, _
                                              TargetSortColumn As String, _
                                              HaveHeader As Boolean, UseHeaderRow As Boolean)

     Dim lColumn As Long
        Dim lCount As Long
        Dim lRow As Long

        Dim rsCon As Object
        Dim rsData As Object

        Dim szConnect As String
        Dim szSQL As String

        lRow = Range(TargetRange).Row
        lColumn = Range(TargetRange).Column

        ' Create the connection string.
        If HaveHeader = False Then                                                          'No there is NOT a header row.
            If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
                szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                            "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                            "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=No"";"
            Else
                szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                            "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                            "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=No"";"
            End If
        Else                                                                                'Yes there is a Header Row
            If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
                szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                            "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                            "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes"";"
            Else
                    If (Right(SourceFile, 4) = ".csv") Then
                        szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                                    "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                                    "Extended Properties=""text; HDR=Yes; FMT=Delimited; IMEX=1;"""
                    Else
                        szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                                    "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                                    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes"";"
                    End If
            End If
        End If

        If SourceSheet = "" Then                                                            'Create query strings

            szSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & SourceRange$ & " ORDER BY sku;"

        ElseIf SourceSheet = "DiamondAvian" Or SourceSheet = "export" Then
            szSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & SourceSheet$ & "$" & "] WHERE price IS NOT NULL ORDER BY " & TargetSortColumn & ";"   'Drops all rows with no Price

        Else

            szSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & SourceSheet$ & "$" & SourceRange$ & "] WHERE sku IS NOT NULL ORDER BY " & TargetSortColumn & ";"   'THIS WORKS FOR DICIONARY

        End If

        On Error GoTo SomethingWrong

        Set rsCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        Set rsData = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

        rsCon.Open szConnect
        rsData.Open szSQL, rsCon, 0, 1, 1
                                                                                             ' Check to make sure we received data and copy the data
        If Not rsData.EOF Then

            If HaveHeader = False Then
                Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsData
            Else
                                                                                             'Add the header cell in each column if the last argument is True
                If UseHeaderRow Then
                    For lCount = 0 To rsData.Fields.Count - 1                                'Builds the Header row one column at a time.
                        Cells(lRow, lColumn + lCount).value = rsData.Fields(lCount).Name     'lcount determines the Column to paste header info in.
                    Next lCount
                Cells(lRow + 1, lColumn).CopyFromRecordset rsData                            'This is the step that copies and Pastes the data.
                Else
                    Cells(lRow + 1, lColumn).CopyFromRecordset rsData
                End If
            End If

        Else
            MsgBox "No records returned from : " & SourceFile, vbCritical
        End If

        rsData.Close                                                                        ' Clean up our Recordset object.
        Set rsData = Nothing
        rsCon.Close
        Set rsCon = Nothing

        Exit Sub

SomethingWrong:

    MsgBox "The file name, Sheet name or Range is invalid of : " & SourceFile, vbExclamation, "Error"

On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Sample data from export.csv

```
sku    price    post_date        post_date_gmt
B1     - M      4/19/2015 11:15   4/19/2015 15:15
B8     8.06     4/19/2015 11:11   4/19/2015 15:11
B1     10.79    4/19/2015 11:08   4/19/2015 15:08
B2     11.65    4/19/2015 11:08   4/19/2015 15:08
B3     11.98    4/19/2015 11:08   4/19/2015 15:08
B3B    12.74    4/19/2015 11:08   4/19/2015 15:08
B4     16.24    4/19/2015 11:08   4/19/2015 15:08
SB     770      4/3/2015 12:37    4/3/2015 16:37
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not using the path to the directory that holds the csv file in the szConnect string.  I was using the file name not the path.

I added a string "strWorkingDir" and set it equal to the directory of the files and now It works fine.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974559.aspx

CraigM

Answer (score 1):

SQL does not support the `<>` operation on Null.  Replace

```
"SELECT * FROM [export$] WHERE price <> NULL ORDER BY sku;"
```

with

```
"SELECT * FROM [export$] WHERE price IS NOT NULL ORDER BY sku;"
```

This similar question explains the rationale.  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5658472/3529814)

Comment: I made the IS NOT change.  The ADODB.Connection and the ADODB.Recordset remain with their values of "" and the subroutine still goes into the error trap.