# OrmLite does not bring results on "where" with "not equals" comparator and null column values

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, ormlite

What's wrong with this line?

```
qB.where().ne(AppConstant.SYNC_STATUS_FIELD_NAME, strSyncOK);
```

i'm doing a simple where not equals with ORMlite and brings 0 results no errors:

full code:

```
dao = DaoManager.createDao(connectionSource, clazz);
QueryBuilder qB = dao.queryBuilder();
SelectArg strSyncOK = new SelectArg(AppConstant.SYNC_OK); // ==> "OK" string
qB.where().ne(AppConstant.SYNC_STATUS_FIELD_NAME, strSyncOK);
List<T> var = dao.query(qB.prepare());
```

When i remove the line

```
qB.where().ne(AppConstant.SYNC_STATUS_FIELD_NAME, strSyncOK);
```

all is ok.

When the line is there, no results found, i checked data and all data with AppConstant.SYNC_STATUS_FIELD_NAME is null

Parameter:

```
public static final String SYNC_OK = "OK";
```

Output:

```
SELECT * FROM `Evento` WHERE `syncStatus` <> ?
```

i'm missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this a Sqlite FAQ and not an [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) problem.  If you try it directly:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE table1 (foo int, bar string);
sqlite> INSERT INTO table1 (foo, bar) VALUES (1, 2);
sqlite> INSERT INTO table1 (foo, bar) VALUES (2, null);
```

Now we look at the queries:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE foo == 1;
1|2
sqlite> SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE foo == 2;
2|
```

*Notice* that when we say bar != a value, the null field is not matched:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE bar != 3;
1|2
```

*However* when we use Sqlite's `IS NOT` operator, it *does* match the `null`:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE bar is not 3;
1|2
2|    <---- here it is!!
```

I believe that this is due to [Sqlite's null handling](https://www.sqlite.org/nulls.html) although I can't find the specific docs on it.  [Sqlite's IS NOT documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#isisnot) mentions it somewhat but again not specifically.

Aha.  Here's the reference to read: [Not equal <> != operator on NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658457/not-equal-operator-on-null)

Comment: Ok, nice example, has a bit of logic, should be more explicit that comparators...
Ok now what is the equivalent in ORMLite for "is not" ?

i look only 3 options: .isNull(field) , .isNotNull(field) and .not(where) --- I supose is the .not(where) how can i implement it?

Comment: Well you can do an `and(...)` query with a `isNotNull(...)`.  Another solution is to use the `rawComparison(...)`.