# SQL where clause not differentiate between '-' and NULL

Tags: sql

```
select A from table1 where A <> '-'
```

This query excludes `-` and also the null values. Why the null values?

Comment: Tag DBMS,show input, show desired output.

Comment: Null's are not excluded, they are not included...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> <> is Standard SQL-92; != is its equivalent. Both evaluate for values,
>   which NULL is not -- NULL is a placeholder to say there is the absence
>   of a value.
>
> Which is why you can only use IS NULL/IS NOT NULL as predicates for
>   such situations.
>
> This behavior is not specific to SQL Server. All standards-compliant SQL dialects work the same way.

See Reference Here:

[Not equal <> != operator on NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658457/not-equal-operator-on-null)

Just look for the proper keywords for you to browse for results to your problem efficiently

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` values are always exluded if you don't include them explcitely via `IS NULL`. NULL means not *unknown*. You can't select them with `= NULL` or omit them with `<> NULL`. Any comparison with `NULL` results not in `true` or `false` but in *unknown*.

You have to use

```
SELECT A from table1 where A IS NULL OR A <> '-';
```

another way using `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT A from table1 where COALESCE(A, '') <> '-';
```

Read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Null_or_three-valued_logic_.283VL.29

Comment: Thanks Tim, but my question is different. i am using condition where A <> '-' (dash) but this condition also exclude my null values from table

Comment: @DatabasePirate: yes, that's what i was trying to say with my answer. `NULL` values are never included in the resultset unless you don't ask for them with `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`. A comparison with NULL (like you do with `NULL <> '-'`)  will always result in `NULL` not in `true`/`false`. `NULL` is neither equal nor unequal to any value, even to another `NULL` value. In some rdbms you can deactivate this behaviour, f.e. in SQL-Server with `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF`.