# MySql confusion between empty value (i.e. '') comparision against NULL

Tags: mysql

Answer: [Not equal <> != operator on NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658457/not-equal-operator-on-null)

Here is my table

```
+-------------+
|     test    |
+-------------+
| col1 | col2 |
+------+------+
|      | test |
+------+------+
| NULL |      |
+------+------+
```

---

**Case 1:**

Now when I fire a query

> `SELECT * FROM test WHERE col1 = '';`

MySql Return first row as it contains an empty value.

While row#2 contains NULL value in col#1 which is `NOT` equal to `EMPTY VALUE`

So the second row is omitted in result set.

This is as expected.

---

**Case 2:**

But when I change the query to

> `SELECT * FROM test WHERE col1 != '';`

I get an empty record set, which should be exact opposite of the previous query result.

As empty value check against `NULL` value is failed in that case `NULL` should be `NOT EQUAL` empty value.

So for `!=` check result set should contain row#2 as result, which is not happening in actual scenario.

Instead MySql returns an empty result set.

What I want is to understand this behavior of MySql for empty value comparison for queries like these.

**P.S.** : Please do not post

> Use `IS NULL and IS NOT NULL` operators instead of empty value.

Comment: Not a duplicate try to understand what i am asking instead of marking and editing please read queries and explanation below @martinsmith

Comment: There is no difference in the behaviour of `NULL != ''` and `'' != NULL`. Or whether it is a NULL literal or a column containing NULL. The reason you don't get that row back is explained in the dupe. You are comparing an empty value *with NULL*.

Comment: So what you are saying is using `=` and `!=` operators `NULL` values are always going to be omitted??

Comment: Yes. So you would have to include an `OR Col1 IS NULL` if you wanted to also bring back nulls.

Comment: Understood completely thanks alot @MartinSmith