# How to query for potentially null value with Java NamedParameterJdbcTemplate

Tags: java, sql

Here's an example of how I'm using a `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`:

```
SqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource("column1", value1)
                                            .addValue("column2", value2)
                                            .addValue("column3", value3);
List<String> values = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query("SELECT column4 FROM my_table WHERE column1=:column1 and column2=:column2 and column3=:column3", params, (rs, numRow) -> {
    return rs.getString("column4");
});
```

This usually works just fine, but I've got a case where `value2` can be null. Then it doesn't work because [null can't be compared normally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658457/not-equal-operator-on-null).

How do I get `namedParameterJdbcTemplate` to handle the case where I'm looking for a null?

To be clear, for the SQL query to be correct it would need to evaluate to `WHERE ... and column2 is null ...` instead of  `WHERE ... and column2=null`.

Comment: What do you want to happen when that column is NULL?

Comment: @TomH I added that to my question. It would need to evaluate to `column2 is null`

Answer (score 5):

Try using:

```
SELECT
    column4
FROM
    my_table
WHERE
    (column1=:column1 OR (column1 IS NULL AND :column1 IS NULL)) and
    (column2=:column2 OR (column2 IS NULL AND :column2 IS NULL)) and
    (column3=:column3 OR (column3 IS NULL AND :column3 IS NULL))
```

Alternatively, you could try using `COALESCE`:

```
COALESCE(column1, '') = COALESCE(:column1, '')
```

That's assuming that you want to equate an empty string with `NULL`. Also, this will preclude using any index(es) on `column1`, so be aware of that.

You could also try to change your query string based on the values of :column1, 2, and 3 - adjust it to use `=` or `IS NULL` appropriately.

Comment: This solution is not suitable if you want to take advantage from an index in the column.

Comment: That would be why I said, "Also, this will preclude using any index(es) on column1, so be aware of that."