# SQL - How do I exclude results from a table if they have the same data in two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

For example, I have a Cargo Shipment table and within that table there are two columns; Origin and Destination. How would I make it so that any results I get from my select statement will be excluded if the values in these columns are the same?

To be more specific, I could have a row where both Origin and Destination equals 'Chicago', how would I exclude that row without also excluding rows that have either Origin **or** Destination as Chicago.

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that it should only be for a specific origin and destination, so if they were both for example 'Dallas' I would want that to show, but if they are both 'Chicago' I don't want that to show'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Cargo
WHERE
    Origin != Destination
```

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you! Do you know how to exclude a specific name for the origin and destination so that all other duplicates can be allowed?

Comment: Could you clarify your last question? Are you asking how to exclude a specific value if it appears as both origin and destination, but allow other duplicated values? If so you could use `SELECT * FROM Cargo WHERE Origin <> 'val' OR Destination <> 'val'`

Comment: That's exactly what I was asking, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: No problem. Also, if you wanted to do something similar with a list of values, you could use something like `SELECT * FROM Cargo WHERE Origin <> Destination OR  Origin NOT IN ('list', 'of', 'vals')`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the WHERE clause to exclude all rows where the origin and destination both equal a specific value using

```
SELECT *
  FROM SHIPMENTS
 WHERE ORIGIN <> 'val'
       OR DESTINATION <> 'val'
```

or, if you wanted to exclude all items where the origin and destination are in a list of values, you could use

```
SELECT *
  FROM SHIPMENTS
 WHERE ORIGIN <> DESTINATION
       OR ORIGIN NOT IN ('list', 'of', 'vals')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to compare the two columns use the not equal operator =! or <> in your where clause, depending on your needs.

select...
where Origin != Destination

Hope it helps.

Here you have a post about this operators [Not equal <> != operator on NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658457/not-equal-operator-on-null)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: for the change requirement

```
SELECT *
FROM SHIPMENTS
WHERE ORIGIN <> 'Chicago' AND DESTINATION <> 'Chicago'
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this! Would this also work if I used the like clause to exclude results that start with the same city name? For example, if i added                                                                                                               and
                        (OriginName not like 'Chicago%' and DestName not like 'Chicago%')

Comment: Of course it must address that and other required conditions as well.