# Dql query with optional parameters

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I would like to know how to make a DQL query with optional parameters for exemple:

```
public function getUsers($city, $sex, $age)
    {
        $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('u')
            ->where('u.sex = :sex')
            ->andWhere('u.city = :city')
            ->andWhere('u.age = :age')
        ->setParameter(':city', $city);
        ->setParameter(':sex', $sex);
        ->setParameter(':age', $age);
        $query = $qb->getQuery();
        $result = $query->getResult();

    }
```

How to do if one of the parameters is not defined(=NULL) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function getUsers($city, $sex, $age)
{
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('u')
        ->from('User', 'u');

    if (isset($sex)) {
        $qb->andWhere('u.sex = :sex')
           ->setParameter(':sex', $sex);
    }

    if (isset($city)) {
        $qb->andWhere('u.city = :city')
           ->setParameter(':city', $city);
    }

    if (isset($sex)) {
        $qb->andWhere('u.sex = :sex')
           ->setParameter(':age', $age);
    }

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();    
}
```

Comment: Works well when I replace all 'where' by 'Andwhere'

Comment: My bad. Thanks @user6533866

Comment: Haven't you just reinvented ‘findBy‘?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, a parameter setted to `NULL` could have sense, because, even if it is not standard, you can express `IS NULL` condition with (just for the sake of example) `u.age = :age` where `age` is `NULL` (I suggest to [read this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658457/not-equal-operator-on-null) however)

So, it's pretty clear that you need to check it yourself (if you intend them as optional) and don't add condition (and so parameter bind) if that parameter is `NULL`.

Pay attention that if `sex` (that's listed as first parameter) is null, you should use `where` against `andWhere` in second `where` condition and so on.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation, So what code do you suggest ?

Comment: You can use only `andWhere` conditions: `$qb = ... ; if(!is_null($myParam)) $qb->andWhere('param = :myParam')->setParameter('myParam', $myParam); $query = ...`

Answer (score 0):

The other comments are correct! However, if you'd like to avoid an if-statement chain you could use the following:

A UserStore containing:

```
public function search(...UserSearchFilter $filters): array
{
    $alias = 'u';
    $qb = $this->repository->createQueryBuilder($alias);

    foreach ($filters as $filter) {
        $filter->apply($qb, $alias);
    }

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Somewhere in your code where you need the result:

```
$this->userStore->search(
    new CityFilter($city),
    new SexFilter($sex)
);
```

Example filter:

```
final class CityFilter implements UserSearchFilter
{
    public function __construct(
        private readonly string $city,
    ) {}

    public function apply(QueryBuilder $queryBuilder, string $alias): void
    {
        $queryBuilder
            ->andWhere(\sprintf('%s.city = :city', $alias))
            ->setParameter('city', $this->city);
    }
}
```