# Northwind database | SQL query that returns employees and who they report to

Tags: sql, northwind

I am trying to write a query for the Northwind database that lists the employees and their manager's names, without including employees who have no one to report to.

**Here is what I have so far:**

```
SELECT employees.firstname, employees.lastname, superior.firstname, superior.lastname
FROM employees 
LEFT OUTER JOIN employees superior ON employees.reportsto = superior.employeeID 
WHERE employees.reportsto <> null;
```

This query runs, but nothing appears.

Comment: Sorry about the checking and unchecking the answer buttons for you guys repeatedly! I thought that I could pick more than one answer. 

Comment: Tip of today: Declare table aliases for both employees instances, to make the code clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try:

```
SELECT employees.firstname, employees.lastname, superior.firstname, superior.lastname
FROM employees 
LEFT OUTER JOIN employees superior ON employees.reportsto = superior.employeeID 
WHERE employees.reportsto IS NOT NULL --or "<> NULL" when ANSI_NULLS is set to OFF ("!=" is specific to SQL server)
```

If you are using `sql server`, the default is to `set ANSI_NULLS` ON, you need to use `IS/IS NOT` to compare with `NULL`

Comment: It is about **without** including employees who have no one to report to so it should be IS NOT NULL

Comment: @RandikaRatnayake, my bad eyesight

Answer (score 0):

Try **IS NOT NULL**:

```
SELECT employees.firstname, employees.lastname, superior.firstname, superior.lastname
FROM employees 
LEFT OUTER JOIN employees superior ON employees.reportsto = superior.employeeID 
WHERE employees.reportsto IS NOT NULL;
```

Explanation:
NULL has no value, and so cannot be compared using the scalar value operators.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5658472/684030

Comment: Pleasure. Mark as the answer if that help you :)

Comment: Sorry! The other person beat you to it by 4 minutes, but I really appreciate the help! If I could pick multiple answers I absolutely would, but thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

I got it, never ever ever try to compare a value to null. The proper answer is:

```
WHERE employeesAM.reportsto **is not** null;
```

Comment: you could use `=` or `<>` (`!=`) to compare with `NULL` only if you set the query option `SET ANSI_NULLS` to OFF

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT empa.employeeid, 
       empa.firstname, 
       empa.lastname, 
       empb.firstname AS 'Reports to Manager' 
FROM   employees empa 
       INNER JOIN employees empb 
               ON empa.reportsto = empb.employeeid
```