# What Exactly does the <> operator do in HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

It doesn't say exactly in the docs.  I have seen this refer to not equals in other instances but HQL already has !=

If it does mean not equals how is it different from !=   ?

I'm sorry if this question has been asked before, but I wasn't able to find an exact explanation for it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658457/not-equal-operator-on-null

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The SQL standard defines *not equals* as `<>`; HQL is SQL-like so follows suit.

Some database dialects (also) support `!=` as the *not equals* operator, some only support `!=`, others only `<>`; but for dialects that support both, the behaviour is the same (at least, I am not aware of dialects where they behave differently).

Comment: Ok so <> is interchangeable with !=.  Thanks

Comment: Actually, `!=` is not part of the SQL standard (but most DBs support it)