# Counting NULL values in a case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following SQL Query:

```
SELECT jobs.ID,  jobs.title,
SUM(CASE WHEN jobresponses.result = 'true' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as True,
SUM(CASE WHEN jobresponses.result = 'false' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as False,
SUM(CASE WHEN jobresponses.result != 'true' AND jobresponses.result != 'false' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Incomplete
FROM jobresponses 
JOIN jobs on jobresponses.jobId = jobs.ID
WHERE jobs.ID = 1
GROUP BY jobs.ID, jobs.title
```

The third case expressions is in practice counting values with a `result` of `NULL`, but to be safe (between `''`, `undefined` and `NULL`) I wanted to basically have a catch all "other" type field. However, the issue is that the NULL values aren't being counted. See [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dd62e/2) SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Case _expressions_, not statements.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not equal <> != operator on NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658457/not-equal-operator-on-null)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`IS NULL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/is-null-transact-sql):

```
SELECT jobs.ID,  jobs.title,
SUM(CASE WHEN jobresponses.result = 'true' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as True,
SUM(CASE WHEN jobresponses.result = 'false' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as False,
SUM(CASE WHEN jobresponses.result IS NULL                      -- detect NULL
              OR jobresponses.result NOT IN ('true', 'false')  -- other values
   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Incomplete
FROM jobresponses 
JOIN jobs on jobresponses.jobId = jobs.ID
WHERE jobs.ID = 1
GROUP BY jobs.ID, jobs.title;
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/JHJKE3692)**

Answer (score 1):

`NULL = NULL` evaluates to `NULL`, which is neither true nor false.  If you want to catch anything that's not `'true'` or `'false'` then you can use use

```
SUM(CASE WHEN (jobresponses.result = 'true' OR jobresponses.result = 'false') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as Incomplete
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way of doing this reverses the `then`/`else` logic:

```
SELECT j.ID,  j.title,
       SUM(CASE WHEN jr.result = 'true' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as True,
       SUM(CASE WHEN jr.result = 'false' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as False,
       SUM(CASE WHEN jr.result IN ('true', 'false') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as Incomplete
FROM jobresponses jr JOIN
     jobs j
     ON jr.jobId = j.ID
WHERE j.ID = 1;
GROUP BY j.ID, j.title
```

Answer (score 0):

you can query as below:

```
SELECT jobs.ID,  jobs.title,
SUM(CASE WHEN jobresponses.result = 'true' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as True,
SUM(CASE WHEN jobresponses.result = 'false' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as False,
SUM(CASE WHEN jobresponses.result is null or ltrim(rtrim(jobresponses)) = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Incomplete
FROM jobresponses 
JOIN jobs on jobresponses.jobId = jobs.ID
WHERE jobs.ID = 1
GROUP BY jobs.ID, jobs.title
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use ISNULL(). It will work, but it is a T-SQL function. Use COALESCE() instead. It's multi-platform.

```
SUM(CASE WHEN COALESCE(jobresponses.result,'') = 'true' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as True,
SUM(CASE WHEN COALESCE(jobresponses.result,'') = 'false' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as False,
SUM(CASE WHEN COALESCE(jobresponses.result,'') NOT IN ('true','false') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Incomplete
```

Also, are the only valid values for `jobresponses.result` supposed to be 'true', 'false' or null? If so, you'd be better off making that field a `bit/Boolean` instead of a `varchar()`. It would significantly reduce storage requirements and be a lot easier and more efficient to work with.

Comment: NOTE: If it was a `bit` datatype, you'd have to have more care on validating your input to the database (which isn't a bad thing anyway), and then you'd only have to worry about 1,0 and null. Then you wouldn't have to worry about weird data like `undefined` or `''` working it's way into your data.