# why mysql show wrong output?

Tags: mysql, sql

Mysql Query

```
SELECT * FROM `jobc_labor` WHERE type='Workshop' AND  RO_no='4' AND (status!='Job Not Done' OR status!='Jobclose')
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiUgt.png)

Also tried

```
SELECT * FROM `jobc_labor` WHERE type='Workshop' AND  RO_no='4' GROUP BY `RO_no` HAVING status!='Job Not Done' OR status!='Jobclose'
```

AND tried with <> but same result

```
SELECT * FROM `jobc_labor` WHERE type='Workshop' AND  RO_no='4' AND (status<>'Job Not Done' OR status<>'Jobclose')
```

My question is why mysql giving my output of the rows which has status of 'job Not Done and Jobclose??? What I am doing wrong. I want to write the query which check wether all labor type with workshop has jobclose or job not done OR they are empty which means the work is in process. please help.

Comment: Handle NULLs properly

Comment: @KaushikNayak will you please explain?

Comment: Go through the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658457/not-equal-operator-on-null

Comment: The first and last statements are the same (and the condition should be = ) , the second is inappropriate because there is a group by without any aggregations. Define empty do you mean null or empty string - they are not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Your status condition:

```
AND (status!='Job Not Done' OR status!='Jobclose')
```

is always true because when status is equal 'Job Not Done' then status is not equal to 'Jobclose' and vice-versa.

You can change it to:

```
AND status!='Job Not Done' 
AND status!='Jobclose'
```

or use NOT IN:

```
AND status NOT IN ('Job Not Done', 'Jobclose')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This query:

```
SELECT * FROM `jobc_labor` 
WHERE type='Workshop' AND  RO_no='4' AND status not in ('Job Not Done','Jobclose');
```

When you put `or` , you need be to more careful.