# "where not in" - bizarre return in a simplest query

Tags: oracle

I'm hitting the wall how to interpret this:

```
select * from (
  select '123' id1 from dual
) src
where src.id1 not in (select id1 from table1)
;
```

Gives me no rows

```
select * from (
  select '123' id1 from dual
) src
where src.id1 in (select id1 from table1)
;
```

Also gives me no rows.

How is this possible in both cases?

Where not exists, on the other hand, works as intended. Table1 is not empty. 
And actually, yes - table1 has both nulls and non-nulls. Why would that make opposite conditions *both* wrong?

EDIT:
Not full duplicate, since the listed similar question was why results are different, whilst here - why results are the same on an opposite condition - which may be confusing.

Comment: You should illustrate this question with sample data. Does `select id1 from table1` return (only/some) `NULL`s by any chance?

Comment: Could you make it an answer? I'll mark it as achieved.

Comment: Guessing from no sample data given: Looks like `table1` doesn't include `'123'` but `NULL` in `id1`. Why the `IN` isn't true is obvious. For the other case see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129077/not-in-clause-and-null-values (though it's about SQL Server, the same applies to Oracle)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NOT IN clause and NULL values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129077/not-in-clause-and-null-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your list of ids to test against contains `NULL` values.

[Comparisons with NULL always return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658457/not-equal-operator-on-null). Even `WHERE NULL = NULL` is false (same as `WHERE NULL != NULL`). You'd need to use `IS NULL`.

In your case, you probably want `select id1 from table1 where id1 is not null`