# Where is null or not equalent value does not return record in mysqli

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to fetch the records from two tables.

1 - tokens 2 - transactions

In both tables there is same column user_id and tokens table has transaction_id. I am trying to get all transactions which has relation with token. I am trying following

```
select sum(`amount`) as aggregate 
from `tokens` 
where `user_id` in (15, 713, 49, 58, 60) 
and exists 
    (select * 
    from `transactions` 
    where `tokens`.`transaction_id` = `transactions`.`id` 
    and (`custom` != 'BB' or `custom` is null)
    )
```

When I change operator in my query like ``custom`is not null` then I am getting the record, but `not` means query will show the record of `'BB'`.

I have searched about it and found a good sentence from this [**thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658457/not-equal-operator-on-null#5658480)

> NULL Cannot be compared to any value using the comparison operators. NULL = NULL is false. Null is not a value. The IS operator is specially designed to handle NULL comparisons.

So in `custom` I have only one value which is `BB` and another is `NULL`.
My above query is not working.

Can someone kindly guide me how can I resolve the issue?

Comment: Can you provide with sample data in `transactions` table? Also for testing purposes test only sub-query alone, not including it in `SELECT FROM tokens`

Comment: You might mean `AND custom IS NOT NULL`

Comment: please show sample table data and expected result. And then we can tell you exactly what to write without guessing. Thanks.