# NULL variable not getting results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query :

```
DECLARE @dt AS DATE = NULL;

SELECT orderid, shippeddate
FROM Sales.Orders
WHERE shippeddate = @dt;
```

I have some Orders with NULL shippeddate but they are not returned when executing the above query.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not equal <> != operator on NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658457/not-equal-operator-on-null)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check for `NULL` using `IS NULL`.  So:

```
WHERE shippeddate = @dt OR (shippeddate IS NULL AND @dt IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @dt AS DATE = NULL;

SELECT orderid, shippeddate
FROM Sales.Orders
WHERE shippeddate = @dt  or (shippeddate IS NULL AND @dt IS NULL)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you set ANSI_NULLS to OFF you will get what you want to get but it is not recommended :

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF;
```

In this case predicate that evaluates to UNKNOWN. Obviously, NOT TRUE is FALSE and NOT FALSE is TRUE. However, NOT UNKNOWN remains UNKNOWN. In another way :

> NULL has no value, and so cannot be compared using the scalar value
>   operators.

You have to use `ISNULL()` .

```
DECLARE @dt AS DATE = NULL;

SELECT orderid, shippeddate
FROM Sales.Orders
WHERE ISNULL(shippeddate, '99991231') = ISNULL(@dt, '99991231')
```

Comment: There is no need to use a _magic value_ in solving this problem, i.e. `99991231`, and they are generally a bad habit. (If another clever programmer decided to use the same value as a flag to indicate that an order is "on hold" then things may get interesting.) Using [`is null`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/is-null-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) avoids the issue entirely.