# SQL Statement - Select Where * Not equal to

Tags: sql, excel, where-clause

I am attempting to extract all data where the column "Drive_Status" is not equal to "Success" any help on the below statement would be much appreciated.

```
 SELECT * FROM [Main$] WHERE (Drive_Status <> 'Success')
```

The issue with the statement above is data that is either Null or tagged "Error" in the "Drive_Status" column is not being returned.

The database I am using is Excel Database

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: `WHERE Drive_Status IS DISTINCT FROM  'Success'`

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to include `NULL` values as "not equal" then you need a `NULL` safe operator.  Otherwise, the `<>` returns `NULL`, which is treated as "false" in a `WHERE` clause.

You haven't specified your database, but standard SQL provides one:

```
where Drive_Status is distinct from 'Success'
```

If `Drive_Status` is `NULL`, then this returns `TRUE` rather than `NULL`.

Not all databases support this.  Some use `<=>` as `NULL`-safe equality (that is `NULL <=> NULL` evaluates to true).  In these, you can use:

```
where not Drive_Status <=> 'Success'
```

And in others, you need to be more specific:

```
where Drive_Status <> 'Success' or Drive_Status is null
```

Comment: Thanks for the response and clearly defined, its greatly appreciated. The database i am using is Excel.

Comment: @SeanBailey . . . Then you probably need to use the last solution.

Answer (score 2):

`NULL` [is not a value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5658472/14956277) so you cannot use `<>` to check against `NULL`.

Instead, try the following:

```
SELECT * FROM [Main$] WHERE Drive_Status <> 'Success' OR Drive_Status IS NULL
```

Comment: thanks for the response, when i enter this query an error message is thrown "Expecting a select statement"

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) are you using?