# Why does WHERE clause removes null values from the result?

Tags: sql, teradata, teradatasql

I have a table I want to filter data from. I tried the following query

```
SELECT 
SIS, COUNT(*)
FROM DL_SQ_DEV_INT.SMRY_DAILY_TRAILER_REPORT
GROUP BY 1;

Result:
BL,17386
EQ,3242
FIFO,5747
GR,15655
HOLD,13035
LT BL,20566
LT GR,14615
LT OR,14190
LT PU,13877
LT YE,13683
null,223376
OR,15727
PI,3563
PU,16105
RW,200
TA,6
tbd,25302
WH,1945
YE,14510
```

Now when I add a WHERE clause in it, it filters out the null values. The query is a not equal to (<>). How can I avoid that and still have the null values in my result? Changing null to blank or space?

```
SELECT 
SIS, COUNT(*)
FROM DL_SQ_DEV_INT.SMRY_DAILY_TRAILER_REPORT
WHERE UPPER(TRIM(SIS)) <> 'EQ'
GROUP BY 1;

Result:
BL,17386
FIFO,5747
GR,15655
HOLD,13035
LT BL,20566
LT GR,14615
LT OR,14190
LT PU,13877
LT YE,13683
OR,15727
PI,3563
PU,16105
RW,200
TA,6
tbd,25302
WH,1945
YE,14510
```

Comment: what is `1` represents, can you add your table schema?

Comment: Group by 1 is same as Group by SIS. I will add the schema

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither "not equal" nor "equal" will select a value that is NULL.

SQL uses "three-way logic" where an expression can be **true** or **false** or **unknown**. NULL is the absence of any value at all so it cannot be equal to something, and if it cannot be equal to a compared value it also cannot be "not equal", instead it is unknown.

To overcome this you need to treat NULL explicitly in your where clause, to include NULLs use **OR SIS IS NULL**

```
SELECT 
SIS, COUNT(*)
FROM DL_SQ_DEV_INT.SMRY_DAILY_TRAILER_REPORT
WHERE UPPER(TRIM(SIS)) <> 'EQ' OR SIS IS NULL
GROUP BY 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use this:

```
SELECT 
    SIS, COUNT(*)
FROM DL_SQ_DEV_INT.SMRY_DAILY_TRAILER_REPORT
WHERE TRIM(SIS) IS NULL OR UPPER(TRIM(SIS)) <> 'EQ'
GROUP BY 1;
```

Why does your WHERE clause removes null values from the result: NULL value means the absence of value or value is unknown, so that you can't compare NULL value using scalar value operator, `<> 'EQ'` will return unknown or not true.

You could refer more post about NULL value in sql in sof, eg [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658457/not-equal-operator-on-null) or search in gg

Comment: I usually use COALESCE()

Comment: @JeffDege do you mean using `COALESCE(TRIM(sis), ' ') = ' '` instead of `TRIM(sis) IS NULL`? That is just another style of code, and all would return right result.

Comment: `WHERE COALESCE(UPPER(TRIM(SIS)),'x') <> 'EQ'` would replace the whole line, less code but arguably less easy to understand the intention of the code at a glance

Comment: COALESCE(field, '') <> '' is only difficult to understand the first time you see it. It's a common idiom.

Comment: @JeffDege: The optimizer will not be able to use collected statistics on a COALESCE resulting in a (probaby totally) wrong estimate and *no confidence*. No problem for a simple query like this, but maybe for a complex one with ots of steps.