# SQLAlchemy query: Problems with parameterized filtering with != on columns that are NULL/None

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am currently refining a common data interfacing concept.
I use filter masks in the form of `['key', 'comparison method', 'value']` for data filtering tasks.

Comparison methods are taken from

```py
CMD = {
    "==": lambda x, y: x == y,
    "!=": lambda x, y: x != y,
    "has": lambda x, y: y in x,
    "not_has": lambda x, y: y not in x,
    "in": lambda x, y: x in y,
    "not_in": lambda x, y: x not in y
}
```

Now filtering looks like this

```py
filters = [['id', '==', 6], ["type", "!=", "game"]]

with self.session_factory() as session:
    result = session.query(my_dataclass).filter(
                CMD[f[1]](getattr(my_dataclass, f[0]), f[2]) for f in filters
             ).first()
```

Note that `my_dataclass` is a dynamically generated mapped class, thus the getattr-approach extracts the attribute from the mapped class (e.g. `Media.id`) and forwards it to the lambda expression for comparison resulting in `filter(Media.id == 6, Media.type != 'game')` for the example above. This might look absolutely over-complicated but makes sense in the broader view of the common data interface, so please bear with me here.

For batch-operations the concept works like this:

```py
from sqlalchemy import and_, or_, not_

filters = [[['id', '==', 6], ["type", "==", "game"]], [['id', '==', 1], ["type", "!=", "game"]]]

with self.session_factory() as session:
    result = session.query(my_dataclass).filter(
        or_(
            and_(
                CMD[f[1]](getattr(my_dataclass, f[0]), f[2]) for f in filter_mask
            ) for filter_mask in filters)
        ).all()
```

## The main problem

The concept works just fine for the examples above, until I filter for with `!=` on acolumns, that holds a NULL/None value.
When I add `["inactive", "!=", "X"]` to a filter (where 'inactive' is a sqlalchemy.CHAR column that initiates with NULL/None and is set to 'X' in case of soft deletes) the query results in None.

Filtering for `["inactive", "==", None]` works just fine. Filtering with `"!="` on not-Null/None fields works just fine as well...

I tried to narrow down the problem's possible causes for some time now but just hit a dead end here. Has anyone stumbled across a similar problem?

**Thank you for your time in advance!**

#### Further Information:

Python==3.8, SQLAlchemy==1.4.31

I also tried a more SQLAlchemy-near step-by-step approach with iterative query filtering to sort out the problem:

```
    def filter_query(self, my_dataclass: Any, query: Any, filters: list) -> Any:
        """
        Method for filtering query.
        :param my_dataclass: Data class.
        :param query: Query to filter.
        :param filters: Filter masks.
        :return: Filtered query.
        """
        for filter_mask in filters:
            if filter_mask[1] == "==":
                query = query.filter(getattr(my_dataclass, filter_mask[0]) == filter_mask[2])
            elif filter_mask[1] == "!=":
                query = query.filter(not_(getattr(my_dataclass, filter_mask[0]) == filter_mask[2]))
            elif filter_mask[1] == "in":
                query = query.filter(getattr(my_dataclass, filter_mask[0]).in_(filter_mask[2]))
            elif filter_mask[1] == "not_in":
                query = query.filter(not_(getattr(my_dataclass, filter_mask[0]).in_(filter_mask[2])))
            elif filter_mask[1] == "has":
                query = query.filter(getattr(my_dataclass, filter_mask[0]).contains(filter_mask[2]))
            elif filter_mask[1] == "not_has":
                query = query.filter(not_(getattr(my_dataclass, filter_mask[0]).contains(filter_mask[2])))
        return query
```

But the results are the same.

Comment: The answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5658457/5320906) may help you understand what is going on.  But in short, you need to special case nulls with a where clause like `WHERE col != 'X' OR col IS NULL`.

Comment: Thank you very much, @snakecharmerb. This was indeed the problem.