# How to find empty columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to make a query which will give me the list of not empty data from SQL.
I wrote a query but not working. Please help

```
SELECT * FROM [EmployeePIMSInfo] 
    WHERE [Group] = 'Dhaka' and [SalaryRuleCode] != ('Rule-EXP') and 
    [Status] = 'Active' and Designation = 'Peon' 
    and (EMail != '' or EMail is not null)
```

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results as formatted text

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: You can just use `EMail != ''` - that implicitly excludes `NULL` anyway here

Answer (score 0):

Use **and** instead of **or**

```
SELECT * FROM [EmployeePIMSInfo] 
    WHERE [Group] = 'Dhaka' and [SalaryRuleCode] != ('Rule-EXP') and 
    [Status] = 'Active' and Designation = 'Peon' 
    and EMail != '' and EMail is not null
```

Comment: `and EMail != '' and EMail is not null` is redundant, you can just do `and EMail != ''` as that excludes nulls anyway.

Comment: @Charlieface nulls and empty string

Comment: Again `EMail != ''` *already* excludes nulls also. See eg https://stackoverflow.com/a/5658472/14868997