# Tips on Creating Fields on table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, field

I am having a trouble with regard to table. I have a field here that goes like this.

```
invoice.table
   id
   member_id (related with member table)
   donor_id (related with donor table)
   receipt_no
   currency_type (USD or PHP or YEN)
   rate 
   amount_type (CASH or CHECK)
      if check{ check_no, bank_name, date}
   amount (the amount received)
   date
```

Creating this as a one table would not be a problem. What I am after is about the **`NULL`** values that would be received. Some fields will be left blank while others are not. Any better suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

In practice, it is best to avoid using null values whenever you can.

From the [SQL Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189265(v=sql.105).aspx) page on null values:

> We recommend that you avoid permitting null values, because null values incur more complexity in queries and updates; and also because there are other column options, such as PRIMARY KEY contraints, that cannot be used with nullable columns.

Also take a look at [this](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/85-Why-NULL-Values-Should-Not-Be-Used-in-a-Database-Unless-Required.htm) blog post if you want to learn more about null values. A TLDR version of his post basically states: "Do not allow null values unless absolutely necessary. It will only make it harder for yourself."

And lastly you can check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431182/creating-a-db-table-null-best-practices) which is very similar to yours and explains why using nulls is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

There is no harm in leaving the null values in some fields.

Though for above table I would suggest you make two tables one for check separately and join them using the 'id' which i'm hoping is your primary key.